# Is it fine to prefix a salutation like Dr. Mr. Ms. Prof. etc. with name in authors' names in research papers?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

My question is about rules or formats regarding writing **names of the authors under the title** in research papers sent for publication in academic journals.

In most of the (research) papers published in academic journals, I haven't seen salutation like **Dr., Mr., Ms., Prof.**, etc. before the authors' names (under the paper's title). Is there any rule about writing salutation before authors' names in research papers (if they really are Doctorate or Professor)?

I am from India, and I have seen authors names having such salutations before their names in some of the published papers, but I haven't seen such salutations in the papers of the researchers of other countries. I personally have heard Indian authors insisting journals to write salutations before their names in the papers they sent for publication. I know the mentality of Indians that they want to write salutations in their papers, and they feel too much proud and honoured when anyone call them with the salutations, even during informal social gatherings and events.

I want to let them know about writing salutations in papers before their names if there is any guideline or recommendation. I searched on Google, but found results only related to general usage; I did not found anything specifically related to research paper publication in journals.

Comment: I suspect that the format for author identification is determined by the policy of the journal. There may be conventions particular to a field that most journals in that field will follow.

Comment: I recently heard a mathematician, let's call them M, say "I never write my name as Dr. M unless I'm writing to a medical doctor"... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on field and country. In my humanities field, it used to be quite common to see "Prof. Rossi of the University of Bologna argued X, which became widely accepted due to the work of Dr. Smith at the University of Chicago" in journals until about 40 years ago, but it sounds very old-fashioned now. It was (and is) more common in certain languages than others. Sometimes, we still see titles/positions mentioned if it is germane to the discussion (e.g. if the relationship between several scholars' ideas can be explained by the fact that one of them taught the rest).

If you're asking about authors' names under the title, not in the body of the article, I don't think I've ever seen it in my field - but, again, this would be field-specific.

Comment: If you write it in a submission to a journal you can always remove it if an editor objects. Don't worry too much about such things.

Comment: I asked about authors' own names under the title in their own submitted paper. Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question, and I hope now that all can understand my question properly. Thank you.